# How to connect a button in html to website link

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

I want to create a button in html and CSS that linked to a website
By pressing the button it would linked me to other website

I tried the `<a>` tag but it only linked me to other pages not a whole other website

Comment: Sorry but this is completely unclear.
Could you add some code you are stucking on???

Comment: Use an anchor `<a>` and style it with CSS to look like a button. It's what they're made for

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running into this problem because you tried using the <a> tag with a relative URL as opposed to an absolute one. An absolute URL requires the whole thing, including "http(s)://www.". If you add all of it to the href in the <a> tag, you should be able to redirect externally.

Example if you wanted to redirect to Stack Overflow:

```
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/" class="button">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link#:%7E:text=The%20plain%20HTML%20way%20is,URL%20in%20the%20action%20attribute.&text=If%20necessary%2C%20set%20CSS%20display,type%3D%22submit%22%3E%20.)